# Why cant we set the value of a property created in a structure without creating the constructor of the structure in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

I have created one field and one auto-implemented property of type int in a structure.

Why is it that without creating the constructor for the structure value can be assigned to the field but property value cannot be set?

[image]

**Edit :** Image Updated

Comment: You haven't created `s1` yet: `Mystruct s1 = new Mystruct();`

Comment: Also: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I think that's rather the point of the question: you can assign fields on an uninitialised struct, but not properties

Comment: @canton7 I thought that might be the case but it was unclear from the wording. I guess that's what _without creating the constructor_ is referring to?

Comment: Yeah, I assume they mean "without calling the constructor". It's fairly clear from the code sample

Comment: Nice find on the dup. Wish I'd found that before writing my answer!

Answer (score 4):

From [the language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#instantiation-of-a-structure-type):

> Typically, you instantiate a structure type by calling an appropriate constructor with the new operator. Every structure type has at least one constructor. That's an implicit parameterless constructor, which produces the default value of the type. You can also use a default value expression to produce the default value of a type.
>
> If all instance fields of a structure type are accessible, you can also instantiate it without the new operator. In that case you must initialize all instance fields before the first use of the instance.

So you're allowed to initialise a struct by calling its constructor, or you can declare an uninitialised struct and then manually initialise each of its fields before the first use.

The trick here is that you do need to assign each *field* directly -- you can't call a method which initialises the fields (or a property setter, which is a special type of method). This means that if your struct has auto-properties you can't use this technique, as there's no way of initialising the backing field for the auto-property directly.

(This is because the compiler needs to check that you've definitely assigned to each field. If you call a method / property setter which assigns those fields, the compiler has no way to check what the method is doing, particularly if the struct is declared in a separate assembly meaning it can change).

Comment: I might point out that this is a specifically C# problem/edge case due to the requirement for definite assignment. VB.Net doesn't have this problem. When you assign `s1 = new Mystruct();` both C# and VB issue a `initobj` instruction, which actually initializes all the fields to default anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a problem: it's a weird corner of the spec. The spec could equally have decided to disallow this and enforce that the user calls one of the struct's constructors.